# Using The Labeling Engine API vs. The simple labeling interface API in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, labeling, api, svg

I am working on a project where I am to label city maps. I want to label roads and buildings with text, and some point locations with symbols where I use SVGs and TrueType font.
As labeling result, I want NO labels to be suppressed due to overlapping: all labels must be visible.
I also want to be able to use SVGs and TrueType font, besides plain text.

So far I have tried with using the simple QGIS interface API, e.g. for labeling roads:

```
roads = project.mapLayersByName('layer_name')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(roads)
roadsSettings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
roadsTxtFormat = QgsTextFormat()
roadsTxtFormat.setFont(QFont("Univers LT Std 57 Cn"))
roadsTxtFormat.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
roadsSettings.setFormat(roadsTxtFormat)
roadsSettings.fieldName = "ROADNAME"
roadsSettings.placement = 3 #Curved: 3 Straight: 2
roadsSettings.placementFlags = roadsSettings.OnLine
roadsSettings.repeatDistance = 45
roadsSettings.enabled = True
roadsSettings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(roadsSettings)
roads.setLabelsEnabled(True)
roads.setLabeling(roadsSettings)
roads.triggerRepaint()
```

I am wondering if this is the best method, to add labels one by one for each vector layer, using `QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling`. With this method I can also add SVG symbols using the `QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer` class.

Another method would be to use the Labeling Engine API, e.g. using the `QgsLabelingEngineSettings` class. However, I am not familiar with it, and haven't found many examples of others using it. Furthermore, I don't know if I can use SVG with the Labeling Engine API.
Also, I don't know if one or both of those methods automatically suppresses labels, which I don't want.